# Include get_term_link inside search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, taxonomy, search, terms

I am trying to include custom taxonomy links inside the search.

This is my code that gets the links of my 'help_cat' taxonomy, but I am struggling on how to add/include this inside the search.

```
function getHelpCategoryLink(){
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'help_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'help_cat' );
        echo $term_link;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add it how? As a search result?

Comment: yes. I've read about pre_get_posts hook that it might be able to help me achieve my goal and I am trying it out now, but let me know if there's a better idea or if you have any tips on how to structure my code

Comment: @JacobPeattie not sure if its right to ask you this, but If I am using a multisite setup, does  the way I query data from db change? i've found a solution that joins the posts & terms, but it doesn't work for me. sorry if its a silly question, but im new to wp

Comment: It could affect it. You should post that as a new question and include the code you're trying to use.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've posted a new question as you've suggested and I've tried some other solution found online. This is the link if you want to take a quick look : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/408684/amend-taxonomy-to-search-in-wordpress-admin